# Angular 4+ and Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, angular, routes

I am trying to use my Angular 4+ app in Wordpress, I followed this tutorial:  [tutorial link](http://doppiaeast.com/article/angular-2-wordpress-theme-setup/). My application now works in WordPress, but now I have a problem with routing, because Angular tries to route all URLs, but I want Angular app only on the first page, other routes (like `/blog`) need to be independent.

Maybe anyone knows how to solve this problem, or how to use Angular app with WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Any link that is external or not an Angular route should be linked to using the href attribute, not routerLink.

Answer (score 0):

Although this may not answer your direct question perhaps I can provide an alternate solution.

Using Xo for Angular you may be able to incorporate the blog, powered by WordPress, within your existing Angular App and serve it as a single cohesive experience.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/xo-for-angular/

Xo lets you create all content, pages, posts, media, etc within your WordPress and have those items routed dynamically in your Angular App.

Documentation (work in progress): https://angularxo.io/

Plugin github: https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-core

Example theme: https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-material

It should be possible to copy an existing Angular App to a new theme and let the Xo for Angular plugin load and direct front-end requests to the Angular index. Then you can use the Xo API to retrieve pages and posts within your WordPress. Xo for Angular can also generate dynamic page routes if you decide to let Xo and WordPress take control.

Full disclosure I am the author of the above plugin and theme.

Let me know if you think this could work for you, thanks!